# How to build a High performance VPN using Azure VNet-VNet Peering

Tags: azure, routes, vpn, vnet

Current Setup:

VPN Client(Phone) ---> VM(VPN Server){Eg: Korea Region} ---> {All Internet Traffic}

Performance:
ping: 167ms

New Setup:
VPN Client(Phone) --->VM{Eg: India} <--Peering--> VM(VPN Server){Eg: Korea Region} ---> {All Internet Traffic}

How can I achieve this?
Couldn't find a guide. As far as I know, I wanna forward all traffic to the Korea Region using the VNet-VNet peering. But do I need a VPN server in India too? My goal here is to minimize latency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have an Azure VPN gateway in the same VNet of the VM in the  Korea region. If so, you need to create a VPN gateway in the VNet in the India region then make a VNET to VNET connection between India and Korea region.

You could get more details from [configuring a VNet-to-VNet VPN gateway connection by using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-vnet-vnet-resource-manager-portal).

Comment: Yes but VNET-VNET Gateway is slower than VNET-VNET peering

Comment: In your case, do you want VPN clients in the India region to access the VPN server in Korea Region? If without any VPN in India region, you could get the VM in india region via the remote VPN gateway in  Korea Region via VNet peering, the flow will be VPN clients --->VPN gateway in Korea Region --->peering---->VM and VNet in India. In this method, you could enable gateway transit in the VPN gateway. Does this help you?

Comment: Ahh yes this is great Thanks!